# Creating a Geb Module for UL LI's

Tags: grails, spock, geb

I'm attempting to create a geb module that represents an unordered list of elements.  I've seen examples for how to do this with tables but I'm having a hard time translating that to `UL->LI` elements.  Here's what I have so far:

```
class CheckoutPage extends Page {

  static content = {
    cartItemList { $(".cart_items ul") }
    cartItem { i -> module CartItem,  cartItems[i] }
    cartItems(required: false) { cartItemList.find("li.item") }
  }
}

class CartItem extends Module {
  static content = {
    thumbnail { $("img.book_cover", it) }
    itemInfo { $("div.item_info", it) }
    bookTitle { itemInfo.find("h1").find("a").text() }
  }
}
```

When I do the following in my spec:

```
def "add an item to the cart"() {
   when:
   to CheckoutPage, productId: "10001"

   then:
   cartItems.size() == 1
   def cartItem = cartItems(0)
   cartItem.bookTitle == "Test Book Title 001"
}
```

I get the following error:

> geb.error.UnresolvablePropertyException: Unable to resolve bookTitle
>   as content for cartItems

However, `cartItem` is a DOM element because I can do this and it works:

```
cartItem.find("div.item_info").find("h1").find("a").text() == "Test Book Title 001"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was a combination of both answers given.  I needed those answers to better understand what was happening.  This is the actual solution:

```
class CheckoutPage extends Page {

  static content = {
    cartItemList { $(".cart_items ul") }
    cartItems(required: false) { module CartItem, cartItemList.find("li.item")}
  }
}

class CartItem extends Module {
  static content = {
    thumbnail { $("img.book_cover") }
    itemInfo { $("div.item_info") }
    bookTitle { itemInfo.find("h1").find("a").text() }
  }
}
```

And the test:

```
def "add an item to the cart"() {
    when:
    to CheckoutPage, productId: '10001'

    then:
    cartItems.size() == 1
    def cartItem = cartItems(0)
    cartItem.bookTitle == "Test Book Title 001"
}
```

The reasons (I think) this works is because we're dealing with individual LI elements.  Not a container like a TR with several TD elements.  So the context here is the LI and by using module instead of moduleList, I am only dealing with the individual LI element, and not a list of them.  The cartItems contains the LI elements as a List already.

At least, that is how I understand it and it is working.

Comment: Something doesn't seem quite right to me here. You are passing a parameter to `cartItems` but `cartItems` definition doesn't accept a parameter.. Did you try your code with more than one cart item?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out this blog post. It outlines almost exactly what you're looking for.

http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2010/11/modelling-repeating-structures-with-geb.html

After looking through that blog post, this is what I came up with for your page class:

```
class CheckoutPage extends Page {

  static content = {
    cartItemList { $(".cart_items ul") }
    cartItems(required: false) { 
      cartItemList.find("li.item").collect { item-> 
        module(CartItem, item)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then your module should look like this:

```
class CartItem extends Module {
  static content = {
    thumbnail { $("img.book_cover") }
    itemInfo { $("div.item_info") }
    bookTitle { itemInfo.find("h1").find("a").text() }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had already read that post.  The problem with his OL example is it is not nearly as complex as mine is with all the elements nested in each LI, so I thought a module would be better to encapsulate all that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a bug in your code - you probably wanted to say `def cartItem = cartItem(0)` not `def cartItem = cartItems(0)`. Also, try to avoid using the same names for local variables and your content definitions (like you do for `cartItem`) as it sometimes leads to name clashes which are pretty hard to track down.

You could simplify your content definition by using [`moduleList()` method](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/modules.html#using_modules_for_repeating_content_on_a_page)

```
static content = {
    cartItemList { $(".cart_items ul") }
    cartItems { i -> moduleList CartItem, cartItemList.find("li.item"), i }
}
```

and in your test:

```
then:
cartItems.size() == 1 //here you use it to retrieve the full list
def item = cartItems(0) //here you use it to retrieve a single element
item.bookTitle == "Test Book Title 001"
```